# is there a package to produce random quite english text?

Tags: tex-general

im trying to develop a layoutaware OCR system. I would like to unit test parts of the system by creating controlled random text using certain layouts. Afterwards the resulting images undergo controlled deterioration to emulate the scanning process. Since the random but known text will be available I would be able to train my layout/OCR system.

Comment: I would create text with my favorite program, and then I would `\input` it with the corresponding command.

Comment: `blindtext` and `kantlipsum` produce text in English.

Comment: A newline-separated list of English words is available at http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/share/dict/web2, in case you need one.

Answer (score 12):

The Gutenberg project has piles of English text.  It is not random but there is a lot of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could give a try to Scott Pakin's automatic complaint letter generator. It's amazing and funny:

http://www.pakin.org/complaint/

Alexander

Comment: That is awesome!